# Consider the space of functions real analytic on a complex strip. Is the subspace which consists of functions vanishing at an endpoint Banach?

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

Apologies in advance if this question is not very well-formed, I'm a bit of a beginner in analysis. Anyway, I have the following problem:

Let $\|\cdot\|_{\infty, \Omega}$ be the sup-norm where $\Omega$ is the half plane,  $\Omega=\{z \in \mathbb{C}: \Re( z)< b\}$.
Then the space
$$\mathcal{Z}=\{h:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\mid \|h\|_{\infty, \Omega}< \infty,\; h \text{ is analytic on } \Omega, h \text{ real analytic on } \Omega\cap \mathbb{R}\}$$
is Banach.
Now consider instead the complex strip $\Omega=\{z \in \mathbb{C}:a \leq\Re(z)< b\}$. I am interested in the following class of functions :
\begin{multline}
\mathcal{Z}=\bigg\{h:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{C}\mid \|h\|_{\infty, \Omega}< \infty\; h \text{ is analytic on }\Omega^{o};  h \text{ admits an extension to some domain } \mathcal{D} \\ \text{ with } \Omega \subset \mathcal{D} \text{ such that }, h \text{ is real analytic on } \mathcal{D} \cap \mathbb{R}\textrm{ and } h(a)=0 \bigg\},
\end{multline}

and I wish to prove the above space is Banach. Now, as we have pointwise convergence I assume the condition $h(a)=0$ is not a problem and given a sequence of functions $h_n\in\mathcal{Z}$ then $$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} h_n=h \implies h(a)=0.$$ Forgetting this condition for a second, if I could choose $\mathcal{D}$ once and for all then, as we have uniform convergence of analytic functions, the limit should again be analytic. However, because I cannot specify the domain $\mathcal{D}$ here, I can only say that for each function $h$ there is some **some** $\mathcal{D}$ on which $h$ extends to a real analytic function and one can easily come up with a sequence of functions with decreasing domains of analyticity so that the limit is not real analytic on $\Omega$. However, all of these (that I have thought of), end up converging to some function which blows up at $a$, so it seems like the condition $h(a)=0$ should save the situation and ensure that $\mathcal{Z}$ is Banach, but I'm not quite sure how to prove that formally. Or indeed if it's definitely the case, weird stuff seems to happen in analysis all the time. Any ideas on where I could look or how to think about the problem?

Comment: If the difference between $||h||$ and $\|h\|$ is not conspicuous to you, try this: $||g|| ||h||,\quad$ coded as ||g|| ||h||, versus $\|g\|\|h\|,$ coded as \|g\|\|h\|. I edited accordingly. $\qquad$

Comment: @MichaelHardy I'm sorry, I had started editing when you did yours, and I forgot about the `\|` which I didn't notice was wrong !

Comment: What do you mean by "real analytic" for a complex-valued function on a subset of $\mathbb C$?

Comment: @RobertIsrael. Excuse me, I mean that the function restricted to $\mathbb{R} \cap \Omega$ is a real analytic function. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: Is there any assumption on regularity of those functions off the real line? E.g., as written you do not even require continuity.

Comment: @LukasGeyer, yes I assume that the functions $h$ are analytic on the interior of the strip. Sorry, will add.

Comment: I am still a little confused about your usage of "analytic" vs "real-analytic". Typically "real-analytic" means that both real and imaginary parts of $h(x+iy)$ are analytic functions of $x$ and $y$ (i.e., they are locally represented by a Taylor series in two variables $x$ and $y$). However, it seems to me that you are using "analytic" as complex-analytic, i.e., $h(z)$ is an analytic function of $z$, and "real analytic" as meaning analytic and real-valued. Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: Exact. Apologies if my terminology is off. So $f(z)=1/(z-x)$ for $x$ real, $x$ not in $[a,b]$ would count as an example of such a function, but  $f(z)=1/(z-(x+i))$ would not

Comment: for example let $a_k=a+i-1/k, b_k=a-i-1/k, g_n(z)= \sum_{k=1}^{n}(1/2^k(z-a_k)+1/2^k(z-b_k))$ and let $ f_n(z)=(z-a)g_n(z)$ and it should be clear that $f_n$ is Cauchy, real on the part of real axis in the domain (or conjugat invariantt if you want), $f_n(a)=0$ and $f=\lim f_n$ analytic in the interior of the strip but blows up at $a \pm i$

Comment: @Conrad, damn yes of course you are right.  Ok, I need to think further but thank you!

Comment: No problem - not sure what you need concretely, but the analytic extension beyond the boundary line is quite a strong condition in general (you could be $C^{\infty}$ on the boundary line -both in the sense of derivatives taken on the line as 1-dimensional manifold and in the sense of derivatives continuity from the right to all orders- and still singular everywhere there in the analytic sense)